# Как скрыть записи в блоге от неавторизованных?

Tags: php, wordpress

Вот простое требование. Заходишь на сайт как гость и видишь сообщение типа "авторизуйтесь для просмотра записей", войдя на сайта видны все существующие записи в блога. У знакомого другая cms и там такое требование выполняется легко.
А вот на wordpress найти не могу. Только закрытие на пароль, где заголовок записей виден. Или же полностью закрытый сайт что видна страница входа только.
Такие варианты не подходят. Да и зачем так недоскрывать запись, чтобы был виден ее заголовок а дальше уведомление, что запись на пароле?

Потому вопрос, как можно реализовать скрытие записей от неавторизованных юзеров?
при помощи плагина или кода. возможность еще скрыть одну из категорий записей от неавторизованных.

https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/blog-post-filter/ в этот плагин удалось реализовать то что нужно, но в нем есть нюанс. записи не скрываются в archive.php странице а только на home page.

```
function filterCategories($query) {
            if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        if ($query->is_main_query() && is_home()) {

            $categoryList = array();
            $allowed = get_option('blogPostFilterCategories');
            foreach($allowed as $id=>$status)
                if($status==1){
                    $categoryList[] = $id;
                }
            $query->set('cat', implode(',', $categoryList));
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Скопируйте файл темы, который выводит архивы (категорию записей) в дочернюю тему. Поправьте этот файл таким образом, чтобы не только запись скрывалась, но и заголовки.

Comment: сам плагин так устроен что скрывает только содержимое без заголовка https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/access-category-password/. зато этот плагин работает хорошо. но не вижу смысла не то что в заголовках а вообще в видимости записей что скрыты на пароль. если бы можно как-то изменить вывод записей у этого плагина. или же этот плагин https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/blog-post-filter/ скрывает как раз записи с home page записи из категорий. мне удалось добавить код в 21 строчку. однако плагин работает на homе page. а вот как добавить в архив.php страницу такой код

Comment: @KAGGDesign добавил код в вопросе

Comment: Ну и что за проблема в приведённом куске кода выкинуть `&& is_home()` ?

Comment: да? просто убрать? действительно ничего сложного. но не знал. думал надо дополнить типа is_category(). но убрать еще лучше

Comment: Так ответ дан комментом я его никак не могу отметить как полезный только ответить

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать действие [template_redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) для перенаправления конкретных пользователей на основе ваших условий. Этот крюк действия выполняется непосредственно перед тем, как WordPress определяет, какую страницу шаблона загружать. Это хороший крючок для использования, если вам нужно сделать переадресацию с полным знанием содержимого, которое было запрошено.

Вы можете использовать функцию is_page, чтобы проверить погоду, что текущая страница находится в вашем списке страниц или нет.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );

function redirect_to_specific_page() {
    if ( is_page('slug') && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.dev/your-page/', 301 ); 
        exit;
    }
}
```

Или вместо редиректа вывести надпись что данный блок будет доступен после авторизации.